# subsection text alignment

Tags: tables

trying to make a table appear next to the subsections header, problem is the text appears above the header. Any ideas?

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\title{\textsc{Extra Curricular Achievements}}
\author{Peter Molander}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{titlesec} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Add style 2 if u want different headings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{ntk_logga.jpg}}
\rhead{Föredragningslista\\
Bilaga \textit{fumF{\yearnr}-{\FUM}.7}\\
\today\\}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{
\makebox{}\\
\makebox{}\\
\makebox[0.1\linewidth]{\rule{0.1\linewidth}{0.1pt}} \hspace{1cm} \makebox[0.1\linewidth]{\rule{0.1\linewidth}{0.1pt}} \hspace{1cm} \makebox[0.1\linewidth]{\rule{0.1\linewidth}{0.1pt}} \hspace{1cm} \makebox[0.1\linewidth]{\rule{0.1\linewidth}{0.1pt}} \hspace{1cm}\\}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%% Change font size on section and sub section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% And change the background color  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setkomafont{section}{\mysection}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
    \medium\sf\bf%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0cm}%already boxed
    \colorbox{black!80}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
            \vspace*{2pt}%Space before
            #1
            \vspace*{2pt}%Space after
        \end{minipage}%
    }}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.5em}{1em}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Insert the FUM nr your on 1-8 + Year %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\FUM{8} 
\newcommand\yearnr{19}

\newcommand{\setvalue}[1]{\pgfkeys{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\getvalue}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\declare}[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /variables/#1.is family,
  /variables/#1.unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = ##1}
 }%
}

\declare{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%>START<%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{style1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      Pre-info        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textbf{\Large Fullmäktigesammanträde {\FUM}}\\\\
\textbf{Datum:} 20{\yearnr}-xx-xx\\
\textbf{Tid:} 17:15\\
\textbf{Plats:} Origo\\

%\textbf{Bilagor:}\\ Bilaga 1 - Dagordning\\ %Skall alltid bifogas som bilaga
%Bilaga 2 - Motioner, revisionberättelser etc\\ %Se stadgarna för aktuella bilagor

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      Formalia        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Set Variable1 to the wanted sections start letter %%%%%%
 \setvalue{VARIABLE1 = F}

\noindent\textsc{\section*{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \color{white}{\getvalue{VARIABLE1}{\yearnr}-{\FUM}} 
    & \color{white}{Formalia} 
    %& \color{white}{Anmärkningar}
\end{tabular}}}

%%%% .1 %%%%
\subsection*{\small \getvalue{VARIABLE1}{\yearnr}-{\FUM}.1}
    \begin{tabular}{l} 
        \small Mötets Öppnande \\
    \end{tabular}
        \subsection*{\small \getvalue{VARIABLE1}{\yearnr}-{\FUM}.3} 


    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \small Rapport från enheterna  \\
        \textit{\footnotesize Arbetsmarknadsenheten Bilaga fum\getvalue{VARIABLE1}{\yearnr}-{\FUM}.3a}\\
        \textit{\footnotesize Studiesociala enheten Bilaga fum\getvalue{VARIABLE1}{\yearnr}-{\FUM}.3b}\\
        \textit{\footnotesize Utbildningsbevakningsenheten Bilaga fum\getvalue{VARIABLE1}{\yearnr}-{\FUM}.3c}\\
    \end{tabular}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try with `\begin{tabular}[t]{l}`.

Comment: Yey thanks! It works like a dream!

Comment: You're welcome! B.t.w., `\sf\bf`  are deprecatedfor nearly 25 years. They should be replaced with `\sffamily\bfseries`